# How to get the data from element in HTML with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML code**

```
<body>
       <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

I want to get the data from html element with Javascript

**Javascript code**

```
<script>

        var a =$("cariKod");

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn1").click(function () {
                alert($("#a"))
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: `$("#cariKod").val()` is that you need! [edited]

Comment: var a = $("#cariKod"); and alert(a.val()); it will solve the problem..

Comment: it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with following

```
<script>


     $(document).ready(function () {
        var a =$("#cariKod");   //$("cariKod");
         $("#btn1").click(function () {
                alert(a.val());      //alert($("#a"))
         });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: @A.Gecu try now as 'var a =$("#cariKod");' was written out side of dom ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code : 
Just append .val() while alert

```
<script>

        var a =$("#cariKod");

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn1").click(function () {
                alert(a.val()); 
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: change alert like this alert(a.val())

Comment: Oops..missed that..once again..grateful for showing my mistake :)

Comment: No problem happy to help dude

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you hadn't correctly selected the input: `$("#cariKod")` not `$("cariKod")`.
Secondly, access the value using `.val()`

See this snippet for a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var a =$("#cariKod");

$("#btn1").click(function () {
    alert(a.val())
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
       <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

<button id="btn1">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy paste this code and try with your broswer , not in snippet

```js
$(function(){
 
var $value1 = $('#cariKod').val();
var $value2 = $('#cariAd').val(); 

$('#button').on('click', function(){
 alert('first value is ' + $value1 + '  , second value is ' + $value2);
}); 

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="button">Click me</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function getcar(){
        var cariKod =   document.getElementById("cariKod").value;
        var cariAd = document.getElementById("cariAd").value;
        alert("Cari Kod: " + cariKod + " , " + "Cari İsim:" +  " " + cariAd);
    }
     <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
    <td>
    <textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform" value="">
    </textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <button onclick="getcar()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            a = $('#cariKod').val();
            alert(a);
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <body>
       <table>
<tr>
    <td><label style="text-align:left">Cari Kod:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cariKod" value="" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <label style="text-align:left">Cari İsim:</label></td>
    <td><textarea rows="4" id="cariAd" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><button type="button" id="btn1">Submit</button></td></tr>
```

```
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: is you include jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {

        var value = $("#cariKod").val();
         alert(value);

        });

    });
```

it's worked